# there is issue with my sql developer that after installing it didnt not find some module

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle19c

Warning - could not install some modules: oracle.external.jxlayer - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: E:\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\external\oracle.external.jxlayer.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.external.jxlayer oracle.jewt_olaf2 - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: E:\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\external\oracle.jewt-olaf2.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.jewt_olaf2 oracle.ide.persistence - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: E:\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\ide\extensions\oracle.ide.persistence.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.ide.persistence oracle.ide_boot - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: E:\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\ide\lib\ide-boot.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.ide_boot oracle.peek - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: E:\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\ide\lib\peek.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.peek oracle.ide.vfs - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: E:\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\ide\extensions\oracle.ide.vfs.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.ide.vfs oracle.ide - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: E:\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\ide\extensions\oracle.ide.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.ide oracle.external.woodstox - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: E:\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\external\oracle.external.woodstox.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.external.woodstox oracle.external.pki - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: E:\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\external\oracle.external.pki.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.external.pki oracle.external.miglayout - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: E:\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\external\oracle.external.miglayout.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.external.miglayout oracle.javamodel_rt - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: E:\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\external\oracle.javamodel-rt.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.javamodel_rt oracle.ide_print_api - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: E:\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\ide\lib\ide-print-api.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.ide_print_api oracle.ide.ceditor - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: E:\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\ide\extensions\oracle.ide.ceditor.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.ide.ceditor oracle.ide.library - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: E:\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\jdev\extensions\oracle.ide.library.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.ide.library oracle.external.jdbc - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: E:\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\external\oracle.external.jdbc.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.external.jdbc oracle.external.nlsrtl - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: E:\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\external\oracle.external.nlsrtl.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.external.nlsrtl oracle.idert - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: E:\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\ide\lib\idert.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.idert oracle.javatools_jndi_local - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: E:\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\external\oracle.javatools-jndi-local.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.javatools_jndi_local oracle.icons - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: E:\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\external\oracle.icons.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.icons oracle.uic - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: E:\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\ide\lib\uic.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.uic oracle.ide_osgi - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: E:\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\ide\lib\oracle.ide.osgi.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.ide_osgi oracle.ide.webbrowser - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: E:\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\ide\extensions\oracle.ide.webbrowser.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.ide.webbrowser oracle.external.xmlparser - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: E:\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\external\oracle.external.xmlparser.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.external.xmlparser oracle.external.objectweb_asm - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: E:\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\external\oracle.external.objectweb-asm.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.external.objectweb_asm oracle.javatools_jdk - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: E:\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\jdev\lib\jdkver.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.javatools_jdk oracle.javatools_nodeps - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: E:\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\external\oracle.javatools-nodeps.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.javatools_nodeps oracle.ide.file - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: E:\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\ide\extensions\oracle.ide.file.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.ide.file oracle.external.timing - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: E:\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\external\oracle.external.timing.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.external.timing oracle.java_annotations - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: E:\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\ide\lib\annotations.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.java_annotations org.eclipse.equinox.common - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: E:\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\equinox\org.eclipse.equinox.common_3.6.0.v20100503.jar: Not found bundle:org.eclipse.equinox.common oracle.external.xdk - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: E:\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\external\oracle.external.xdk.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.external.xdk oracle.javatools_exports - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: E:\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\modules\oracle.javatools\javatools-exports.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.javatools_exports oracle.external.xsql - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: E:\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\external\oracle.external.xsql.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.external.xsql oracle.external.balishare - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: E:\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\external\oracle.external.balishare.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.external.balishare oracle.ide.macros - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: E:\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\jdev\extensions\oracle.ide.macros.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.ide.macros oracle.external.xdb - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: E:\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\external\oracle.external.xdb.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.external.xdb oracle.external.ldap - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: E:\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\external\oracle.external.ldap.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.external.ldap oracle.ide.indexing - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: E:\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\ide\extensions\oracle.ide.indexing.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.ide.indexing oracle.ide.searchbar - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: E:\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\ide\extensions\oracle.ide.searchbar.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.ide.searchbar oracle.ide.navigator - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: E:\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\ide\extensions\oracle.ide.navigator.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.ide.navigator oracle.javatools - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: E:\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\ide\lib\javatools.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.javatools oracle.ideimpl.peek - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: E:\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\ide\extensions\oracle.ideimpl.peek.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.ideimpl.peek oracle.external.osdt - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: E:\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\external\oracle.external.osdt.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.external.osdt oracle.jewt_core - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: E:\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\external\oracle.jewt-core.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.jewt_core oracle.javaxide - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: E:\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\ide\lib\javax-ide.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.javaxide oracle.external.berkeleydb - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: E:\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\external\oracle.external.berkeleydb.jar: Not found bundle:oracle.external.berkeleydb

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a corrupted download to me.

I'd advise

- download the SQL Developer version that *includes* the JDK with it.
- unzip it properly, ie, do not just "double click" on the zip file, which opens it up looking like Explorer. You need to unzip it entirely to a folder and run it from there.

Comment: i did this many times but still i get this warning .

Answer (score 1):

In my Amazon WorkSpace this happens a lot. It has always helped to delete "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer" and re-import my connections.